# Visual Studio Mac 2022 database first scaffold dbContext

Tags: entity-framework, terminal, entity-framework-core, visual-studio-mac, visual-studio-mac-2022

I trying to scaffold a MySql database for a new solution in Visual Studio 2022 for Mac. I have installed these packages:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design
MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore
```

Using the `terminal` in Mac OS X, I `cd` to the project directory and enter this command:

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Server=localhost;User ID=root;Password=p@ssword;Database=MyDatabase" MySql.EntityFrameworkCore -o Entities
```

but I'm getting the following error:

```
-bash: !: event not found
```

I have no idea what that error means, can somebody help?